# Provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - only in console application c#

Tags: c#

I have two applications, one works the other gives me a provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40. I simply can't figure out why.

The failing one is a console application with the following code:

```
IRepo<IEntity> repo = new Repo("Data Source=x;Initial  Catalog=x;User ID=x;Password=x");
var q = repo.Query.Where(o => o.attribute == "x").FirstOrDefault();
```

If I do a webforms project in the same solution with the exact same code, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Thinking it had to do with named pipes, I tried with TCP and got a similar error with a 0 code instead. I've looked at the MSSQL server settings, and everything is enabled.

Comment: The server `x` is not reachable. If `x` is not actually `x`, but, say, `x\instancename`, take care that your connection string is escaped properly. See if `x` resolves as a host, if port 1433 is reachable, etc. This is a simple connectivity issue. One way or another, this application does not connect the same way your web forms project does.